# Efficient pairing functions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, computational-complexity, coding-theory, entropy

The standard Cantor pairing function $J:\Bbb N \times \Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ which enumerates antidiagonals is efficient in the sense that it assigns $(m,n)$ in increasing order by $m+n$ (so that this can be viewed as the "complexity metric" that is minimized by this pairing function). But it performs very poorly when one input is much larger than the other; for example $J(0,n)=O(n^2)$, which means that using the pairing function in an unbalanced way for higher tuples, i.e. $J(x_1, J(x_2,\dots, J(x_{n-1},x_n)))$ leads to exponential growth $O(k^{2n})$ when $x_n=k$ and the others are fixed to, say, $0$.

Information entropy analysis suggests that to store two numbers $m,n$ should require approximately $\log_2 m+\log_2n$ bits to store, and a pairing function with this property would show linear growth, not exponential, in unbalanced pairing situations.

Is there a pairing function such that $\ell(J(m,n))\le\ell(m)+\ell(n)+O(\log\log(m+n))$, where $\ell(x)=\lfloor\log_2x\rfloor+1\approx \log_2 x$? (It need not be bijective, just injective, if that makes it easier.) One encoding strategy is to read $\bar m,\bar n\in\{0,1\}^*$ as binary strings, and then form the expression $\bar m\,\$\,\bar n$ as a string in the alphabet $\{0,1,\$\}$, and encode in ternary. But this yields $\ell(J(m,n))=\log_23(\ell(m)+\ell(n)+1)$ which is off by a factor $\log_23$ from optimal.

(Bonus points if you can give an optimal pairing function that uses only standard algebraic operations without resorting to bit tricks like this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode the number $k=\ell(m)$ of bits in $m$ as follows: Encode one bit from $k$, then one bit to signal whether there are more; if so, then two more bits from $k$, then again one to signal whether there are more; if so, then four more bits from $k$, etc., using $O(\ell(k))$ and thus $O(\log\log m)$ bits; then append $m$ and $n$.

Comment: I don't think this is $\ell(m)+O(\log\log m)$ bits. It is in the best case, when $m$ is near a power of two (so the last bin is filled completely), but in the worst case, when $m$ has $1+2+\dots+2^k+1=2^{k+1}$ bits, we allocate an extra block for $m$ of size $2^{k+1}$ and waste $2^{k+1}-1$ bits of it. So it looks like this uses $2\ell(m)+\ell(n)+o(\ell(m+n))$ space (you don't need to encode $n$ in a similar way since it can just end when the output does).

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: Yes, I just realized that and was about to write it :-) I'll delete this and think about it some more...

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: Now I think it should work :-) Just do the same thing for the length of $m$ instead of $m$ itself; then the factor of $2$ is allowed.

Comment: Or, slightly more straightforward: Encode the length with two bits per bit, one signalling whether it's the last. Or encode the length in ternary, as you proposed, with a terminating symbol $\$$.

Comment: Oh, I think you can do slightly better: swap $m$ and $n$ if $m$ is larger at the cost of one bit. That way you achieve $\ell(m)+\ell(n)+O(\log\log\min(m,n))$.